# Creating a Temporary vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have this method I'm trying to complete,  which when completed should construct a limited list of choices from the options vector passed into the method:

```
> int Program::SelectFromMenu(int x, int y, std::vector<std::string> options);
```

For instance, if I wanted to have a menu selection in a bank system, I could add these three strings to my options vector, then the method would display these three choices to the user:

```
 <"Withdraw", "Deposit", "Statement">
```

They pick an option, their decision will call a method. Easy right? I've coded that part already. The problem is getting the vector itself into the method:

In an ideal world, I'd create a temporary vector like this, and use it as an argument:

```
SelectFromMenu(2, 4, <"Withdraw", "Deposit", "Statement">);
```

but I'm unable to do this. What other ways am I able to achieve passing a vector into the method? I mean, I could make a method that constructs the vector from strings I pass in, but that seems like the wrong way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [braced-init-list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```
SelectFromMenu(2, 4, {"Withdraw", "Deposit", "Statement"});
```

Comment: This is literally what the OP is trying to do. +1 (No idea where they got this `<>` idea from)

Comment: Whhops my bad, compiles.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I removed a paramater earlier called menusize since I could derive that from the options.size(), that'sa why it wouldn't compile. Thanks for the help!